# Telerik Controls not displaying correctly --no css

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I have a simple webpage setup for testing.  When I run the website under debug mode the controls display correct.  However, when I move the website over to my server the control don't appear correct.

For example, the DatePicker function only has a link that says "Open the calander popup" instead of the little calander icon like here(http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/calendar/examples/datepicker/custompopup/defaultcs.aspx)

And also the RadComboBox only has `select` instead of the drop down arrow.

There is no aspx.cs to show you guys, however here is my aspx.  I'm pretty sure i'm missing something.

Here is the aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="testingpage.aspx.cs" Inherits="testingpage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
<telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager1" runat="server">
</telerik:RadScriptManager>
<div>
    <telerik:RadDatePicker ID="RadDatePicker1" runat="server">
    </telerik:RadDatePicker>
    <telerik:RadComboBox ID="RadComboBox1" runat="server">
    </telerik:RadComboBox>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I do move the bin folder over which has all the dlls.  I am running .net4.0 in intergrated mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely related to the AXDs generated by the Telerik control - the image popup is an AXD path and is not being dealt with properly on the server.

View source on the page and attempt to browse directly to any of the AXDs (Telerik AXDs) that you can find.

If you have separate web.config files for your server and local machine, compare them for any differences, especially around the httpHandlers.

Ensure that AXDs are being handled in your IIS configuration

Ensure that you have installed/deployed the Telerik DLLs to your server.  Did you install it locally via an installer?  You will want to do that on the server as well.  Does your GAC contain any Telerik.*.dll files?  They should be deployed too.

Comment: OMG that was it the whole freaking time, I had to push the dlls to the server.....

Comment: That fixed the .net3.5 applications but not the 4.0 :/

Answer (score 0):

Couple of suggestions:

a) Firstly, if you deploy this application and run it under IIS in your own machine in "release" mode, does it work properly? (i.e. not running under Visual Studio)

b) If (a) works on local machine, do other ASP.NET applications work on the server? If not, most likely ASP.NET is NOT installed on the server. Check this under "Turn Windows features on and off" under "Programs and Features"

c) If (a) works on local machine and other applications work on server then its likely that the Telerik DLL files are not being published to the BIN folder correctly.

ps. Use Firebug (Firefox) or F12 Developer Tools (IE) which might help you identify the problem.